# Is there a way to remove the RETURNING clause while creating records with go-gorm?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm using go-gorm with a postgres 11 DB and facing an issue where I need to remove the RETURNING clause entirely when creating records (that statement seems to be included by default). I just want to insert records and get nothing back, except for errors.
I have some complex relations on the database that won't support RETURNING statements, so when I try to insert like this: (made code simpler for brevity)

```
type Cargo struct {
    Id   int64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string
}
dsnString := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s ...") 
db, _ := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{DSN: dsnString}), &gorm.Config{})

cargo := Cargo{Name: "test"}
db.Create(cargo)
```

I get the error  "ERROR: cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation Cargo".

I tried creating the db connection with the parameter WithoutReturning: true:

```
db, _ := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{DSN: dsnString, , WithoutReturning: true}), &gorm.Config{})
```

But then when I try `db.Create(cargo)` I get a different error: "LastInsertId is not supported by this driver". It seems to be still trying to get the last inserted id anyway.

In go-pg I could use `db.Model(x).Returning("null").Insert(cargo)` but I couldn't find a way to do it with go-gorm. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What ist he problem? 'RETURNING' is not required. Just remove it. What problem do  you actually have? If you have code producing an error, _include that code in your question_. We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: Gorm uses the RETURNING clause to fill in the primary key of the entity. You can always use the `Exec` call to run your own query for non-entities.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear at my first try. I have inserted a simpler version of the code. Real code has some complex structs inserting on views with some rules behind that make then not happy with the RETURNING statement. I have the code working with go-pg and trying to migrate to go-gorm. Calling `Exec` misses the point of using go-gorm entirely. I just wanted to know if this isn't supported or if I'm missing something as it was so easy with go-pg (just use a .Returning("null")).

Comment: I appreciate that go-gorm is kindly trying to give me the id after insertion, but I don't need it. I just need to disable this behavior when inserting those complex entities. Writing those LONG inserts with Exec would be a great pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two ways that I can get gorm to not use the `RETURNING` clause with postgres are

#### A model that does not declare a primary key

That means getting rid of the field that is named `ID/Id` or any tagged `gorm:"primaryKey"`.

```golang
type Cargo struct {
    Name string
}
db.Create(&Cargo{Name: "Test"})
```

#### Using [Create from map](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-From-Map) with `Table()`

In this case you would represent your model as a `map[string]interface{}` instead of as a struct and use it like this:

```golang
db.Table("cargos").Create(map[string]interface{}{
    "name": "Test",
})
```

As it stands gorm doesn't support this use case very well. If you can't [restructure your views to support RETURNING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createrule.html) and these options aren't doing it for you, I suggest adding a feature request in the [gorm repo](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues).

Comment: Thanks! It worked removing the tags `gorm:"primaryKey"`. I'll have to check for the consequences of that, but at least I got past this early stage of just INSERTING things.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default returning behavior with

```golang
db.Clauses(clause.Returning{}).Create(&cargo)
```

Here the doc link: https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Returning-Data-From-Modified-Rows